# TreeMap and SortedMap conversion statement

Tags: java, debugging, hashmap, treemap, sortedmap

What is wrong with this statement?

```
private final HashMap<String, SortedMap<Long, Long>> abc;
abc = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<Long, Long>>;
```

It shows the error that `SortedMap` cannot be converted to `TreeMap` like this? How do I make this possible?

Comment: Just use type inference, i.e. let the compiler do its work. Use simply: `abc = new HashMap<>()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be able to assign it this way, then can you use a wildcard with bound `? extends SortedMap`. eg:

```
private final Map<String, ? extends SortedMap<Long, Long>> abc;
...
abc = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<Long, Long>>();
```

That said, you don't have to specify the nested map type when you create the new outer hashmap instance.. just keep it as a `SortedMap`. Later when you insert a value it can be new `TreeMap` instances because they implement `SortedMap`. eg

```
private final Map<String, SortedMap<Long, Long>> abc;
...
abc = new HashMap<String, SortedMap<Long, Long>>();
abc.put("Test", new TreeMap<Long, Long>());
```

After shortening this code for type inference, the assignment lines could look like bellow:

```
abc = new HashMap<>();
abc.put("Test", new TreeMap<>());
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't initialized your `HashMap`. Remember to use constructor when you are instantiating new object.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String,SortedMap<Long,Long>> abc;
        abc = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```